# How velocity affects different orbits?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Assume a sun with mass $M$ and a planet with mass $m$. Assume at $t_0$ the planet is $r_0$ (distance) away from sun and has an initial velocity of $v_0$. Also, let’s assume the angle between the $r_0$ and $v_0$ is $\theta_0$ but I suppose if $\theta_0$ is $90$ degrees we can cover all the cases.

Are there any formulas and relations between $M, m, r_0, v_0$ that show wether the planet will make a circular, elliptical, parabolic or hyperbolic orbit ? (Or spiral orbit slowly moving towards the sun making smaller circles ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. Total energy is, in polar coordinates in the plane where the movement occurs:

$$E=\frac{1}{2}\,mv^2-G\frac{Mm}{r}=\frac{1}{2}\,m(\dot{r}^2+(r\dot{\theta})^2)-G\frac{Mm}{r}$$

A short rewrite using $C=\lVert\vec{L}\rVert/m$, the constant from Kepler's second law, yields:

$$E=\frac{1}{2}\,m\dot{r}^2+\underbrace{\frac{mC^2}{2r^2}-G\frac{Mm}{r}}_{=V_\text{eff}(r)}$$

The second and third terms form what's called the *effective potential energy* $V_\text{eff}$. Notice you necessarily have $V_\text{eff}(r)\leqslant E$, which can easily be interpreted on a graph:

[image: Veff]

In this example, $E<0$. Since $V_\text{eff}$ must remain below $E$, the only part of the plot that is physically accessible is $r\in[r_1,r_2]$. In other words, $r$ cannot go to infinity, it's a bound state. This is the elliptic case.

On the other hand, if $E>0$, $r$ cannot go to zero, but it can go to infinity. The movement isn't bounded, it's the hyperbolic case.

The special case $E=0$ is the parabolic one ($r$ can go to infinity, but then kinetic energy is zero).

The special case where $E$ is exactly at the bottom of the potential well is the circular movement (only one allowed value for $r$, here $r_0$).

In other words, the sign of $E$ will tell you exactly in which case you are. $E$ can be rewritten as:

$$E=\frac{1}{2}\,mv_0^2-G\frac{Mm}{r_0}
\quad
\begin{cases}
>0 & \text{hyperbolic}\\
=0 & \text{parabolic}\\
<0 & \text{elliptic}
\end{cases}
$$

which should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If a mass (like a planet) is orbiting a much larger mass (like the sun) under the action of gravity, it has  kinetic energy (1/2)m$v^2$ and potential energy -GMm/r (negative because the zero is chosen to be at infinite r).  If the total energy is negative, the orbit will be elliptical; zero, parabolic; and positive, hyperbolic. The path will be a spiral only if there is a mechanism which is causing a loss of energy. (The earth has been orbiting the sun for a very long time.)

Answer (score 0):

For the planetary motion the total energy
$$E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{GMm}{r} \tag{1}$$
and the angular momentum
$$L=mrv\sin\theta \tag{2}$$
will remain constant for all times $t$.
Hence you can calculate them at time $t_0$
(with $r_0$, $v_0$, $\theta_0$).

From Newtonian mechanic the planetary orbit is known to be a conic section (never a spiral).
Using the values for $E$ and $L$ from (1) and (2) you can
calculate the [eccentricity $\epsilon$ of the orbit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keplersche_Gesetze#Erstes_Keplersches_Gesetz_(Ellipsensatz)).
$$\epsilon=\sqrt{1+\frac{2EL^2}{G^2M^2m^3}}$$

From $\epsilon$ you can read off the shape of the orbit:

- $\epsilon = 0$ : circular orbit
- $0 < \epsilon < 1$ : elliptic orbit
- $\epsilon = 1$ : parabolic orbit
- $\epsilon > 1$ : hyperbolic orbit